# ImageField : how to handle the image file in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
django version: 2.08
MEDIA_ROOT in the settings files
ImageField in the class Product
```

When I add the product to database, the directory `products` is auto made by django, but it is under `myshop` directory, not under the `media` directory.

When I use the Python shell to read the `product.image.url`, it shows:

```
/media/products/2018/08/22/green_tea.jpg
```

the `green_tea.jpg stays` in the `products/2018/08/22/green_tea.jpg`

And in the templates file, I use the following code to get the image path:

```
<img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}">
```

After that, I get the final result, the images can't be showed in the webpage.

I can't figure it out. Could you give me some advice?

[Please see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnh51.png)

Comment: Hi You have to add the media settings in djnago file

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the media url in the settings file.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```